# Installing a win32 service using MSBuild and Microsoft.Sdc.Tasks

Tags: msbuild, windows-services, microsoft.sdc.tasks

I'm trying to install windows service using the Microsoft.Sdc.Tasks library.

```
<ControlService Action="Install"
    ServiceName="Service1"
    User="XXX
    Password="XXX"
    ServiceExePath="$(DeployFolder)\XXX.exe"/>
```

***But I keep getting prompted for the user and password!*** This will not work as I'd like to have it as an automated build on the build server. I mean, the user and password that I want to run the service under are in the actual target. How do I get it to install the service using the configured user and password and not prompt for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/jmanning/archive/2008/04/06/localsystem-root-localservice-nobody.aspx) and since all my service does is writing and reading from local file I should be OK running under the Local Service account instead of a specific user. Even after updated the service installer the *ControlService*-target requires a user and password to run but ***then I actually doesn't*** prompt me for the user and password. But then I don't want to run a specific user and the target fails when not provided with a user and password in the config ... Strange.

I solved by shelling out to the InstallUtil.exe instead. That works fine after set the I set service installer to run as a Local Service account.

```
<Exec WorkingDirectory="C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727"
            Command="InstallUtil.exe -i XXX.exe" />
```

Comment: This will only install the service on the build server.  If you want to install it to a remote server, you should use the servicecontroller task from here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/02/12/438061.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Just an FYI, to install to a remote server, you should use the SericeController task listed here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/02/12/438061.aspx

Comment: The ServiceController task doesn't allow services to be installed. It just controls installed services.