# unable to install window service using 'servicecontroller'

Tags: windows, service, servicecontroller

I want to install a windows service on a remote service. In the following blog you have said to use 'servicecontroller'

[Installing a win32 service using MSBuild and Microsoft.Sdc.Tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469397/installing-a-win32-service-using-msbuild-and-microsoft-sdc-tasks)

However in the 'ServiceController Members' in the .chm file of 'MSBuild Community Tasks'   there is no memeber for accepting the path of the service to be installed for ex. 'c:\myservice.exe'

Please suggest how can i achieve the task of installing service remotely.

Thanks,
Prasad M.

Answer (score 1):

The ServiceController task doesn't allow you to install services. It just controls existing services.

I would recommend using the other approach outlined in the question that you reference:

```
<Exec WorkingDirectory="C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727"
                Command="InstallUtil.exe -i XXX.exe" />
```